# Error in syntax for if statement in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

EDIT FOR THE ADMINS: IT IS NOT THE SAME QUESTION AS THE ONE ALREADY ASKED, SINCE THE ORIGIN OF THE ISSUE IS DIFFERENT!!!

I am trying to display the current language selected, which is saved in the sessions table. 
What I did first was the simple statement:

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata("language"); ?>
```

which works quite well. The problem here is, that the language is saved into the session table in English and lower case, means: "english", "german", "spanish", etc

I then tried to resolve this using an if statement as follows:

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata("language") = spanish) {  echo 'Español'; } else if ($this->session->userdata("language") = english) {  echo 'English'; } else echo 'Deutsch'; ?>
```

unfortunately, this returns:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
>   /home/.../.../.../app/views/header.php on line 270

Any hint on what I am doing wrong? Thanks for your quick help ;)

Comment: I think you meant to use `==`

Comment: @MikeB Thanks, but it is not the same issue. Here it was caused by the missing ==, which was not the case in your quoted question. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a comparison operator `==` (I'm sure your `=` is just the usual common typo), since you can't assign a value (*write*) to the `$this->session->userdata('anything')` (*method return*), i.e.

> Can't use method return value in write context

```
 <?php if ($this->session->userdata("language") == 'spanish') {  
          echo 'Español'; 
        } 
       elseif($this->session->userdata("language") == 'english') { 
          echo 'English'; 
      } 
      else echo 'Deutsch'; 
    ?>
```

Comment: argh... its always the same when someone asks you to "quickly" code something lol Thanks so much, great help!!!

Answer (score 1):

`==` operator and quoted strings should solve it:

```
<?php 
if ($this->session->userdata("language") == 'spanish') {  echo 'Español'; } 
else if ($this->session->userdata("language") == 'english') {  echo 'English'; } 
else echo 'Deutsch'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a **`SWITCH`** Statement to achieve this [*Code will really look readable*]

```
<?php 

$language=$this->session->userdata("language");

switch($language)
{
    case "spanish":
        echo 'Español';
        break;

    case "english":
        echo 'English';
        break;

    //.... goes on



}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two things you should be using the `==` Operator. Also string values should be wrapped into quotes `"myStringValue"`.